# SharePoint 2016 Custom Action to trigger a workflow

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2017, custom-action, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to create a custom action that can be chosen by right-clicking on a file in a any folder of a particular SharePoint Library. This custom action would copy the file into the same folder with the user's login name appended to the end of the file name.

I currently have an event receiver that will perform the custom action when a file is being updated but that's not when I want it to happen. I was able to add a custom action to the right-click file menu using SharePoint Designer but SharePoint Designer only lets the custom action trigger special SharePoint 2010 compatible workflows or load a web page. I need to make it so the event handler (or possibly a workflow) fires when the user chooses the custom action after right-clicking on the file. I'm not sure what approach or what kind of project or app I need to create in Visual Studio 2017 to get this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this using JavaScript, without SharePoint Designer. I put the following script in a Content Editor web part on the page where the listview webpart is and now I can right click on a file and get the option to "Get My Copy". If you have a Comments sub folder, the renamed copy will get put there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// adds the menu option to Get My Copy
function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
    var strDisplayText = "Get My Copy";                  //Menu Item Text
    var strAction = "copyFile()"; 
    var strImagePath = "";                               //Menu item Image path
    CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath);  // Add our new menu item
    CAMSep(m);                                           // add a separator to the menu
    return false;                                        // false means standard menu items should also be rendered
}

// append current user account to filename and copy to subfolder named Comments 
function copyFile()
{
    // get web and current user from context
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    this.currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);

    // load the folder
    var currentFolder = decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder);
    var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(currentFolder); 
    context.load(folderSrc,'Files');

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {            
            // get the first (and hopefully only) file in the folder
            var files = folderSrc.get_files();
            var e = files.getEnumerator();
            e.moveNext()    
            var file = e.get_current();

            // get user account
            var curUserAcct = currentUser.get_loginName();
            curUserAcct = curUserAcct.substring(curUserAcct.indexOf("\\") + 1); 

            // get file without extension
            var file_with_ext = file.get_name();            
            var name_without_ext = file_with_ext.substr(0, file_with_ext.lastIndexOf("."));

            var destLibUrl = currentFolder + "/Comments/" + name_without_ext + " " + curUserAcct + ".docx";     
            file.copyTo(destLibUrl, true);

            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function() { alert("Success! File File successfully copied to: " + destLibUrl); }, 
                function(sender, args) { alert("error: " + args.get_message()) }
            );
        }, 
        function(sender, args){ alert("Something went wrong with getting current user or getting current folder '" + currentFolder + "'. " + args.get_message()); }
    );
}

</script>
```

Comment: Update:  I found a way to keep the FILES and LIBRARY tabs form disappearing. If you use SharePoint Designer you can edit the "All Documents" default view (or better yet, create your own view and edit that) in advanced mode and put the above javascript into the placeholderMain block of the .aspx page.

Comment: you don't need sharepoint designer with my method, i just assumed that this is your way of creating menu items. SPD under the hood creates custom actions, and there is possiblity to create them with SOM, CSOM, JSOM and probably with REST. What you're doing now is using sharepoint global functions used in probably sharepoint 2003...

Answer (score 0):

Your custom action should call `javascript function` or perform `GET request` to your SharePoint hosted `WCF` or `ASMX` WebService.

- ASMX

[Official MSDN Walktrought: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx)

For additional resources with more screenshots check [this blog post: Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010/)

- WCF

[Official Technet Walkthrough: SharePoint 2013: Create a Custom WCF REST Service Hosted in SharePoint and Deployed in a WSP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

*Note*: with `GET request` you will need `web.AllowUnsafeUpdate = true`

With javascript u need `AJAX` call ie [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**/edit**

To hook up web service and your custom action use SharePoint Desinger, delete or change your existing custom action, change type to `Navigate to URL` and in the textbox type:

```
javascript: (function() { console.log('Testing...' + {ItemId}); /* your web service call */ })();
```

Use `{ItemId}` alias to pass proper item id to your AJAX call.

On the other hand, on web service side use `SPWorkflowManager` class to start a workflow on item. Check the code belowe ([link](https://jainnitin2411.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/programmaticallystartsharepointworkflow/)):

```
public void StartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem, SPSite spSite, string wfName)  {
    SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;
    SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = parentList.WorkflowAssociations;
    foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection)  {
      if (association.Name == wfName){
       association.AutoStartChange = true;
       association.AutoStartCreate = false;
       association.AssociationData = string.Empty;
       spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, association,  association.AssociationData);
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I will review the links and see if I can create a Web Service to solve the problem. However I feel like my current roadblock is that I can't find an example to hook up a custom action to a workflow or to trigger an event or web service call. Say I finished a new web service to solve the problem. I would still need to get the custom action hooked up to the SharePoint library and I would need to make it call the web service, or workflow. I feel like I am maybe not looking in the right place or not using the right search terms for this problem.